# UITableView not displaying white cell

Tags: xcode, uitableview

The picture 1 white cell isn't displaying like how it should be in picture 2.

[image]

[image]

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

how are u setting the background image of your tableView? 
It seems u are setting the background of your cell as tableView background.

in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` u must have set the `cell` background same as your tableView using.

```
cell.backgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
```

or

```
cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"]];
```

so remove the line which is setting the cell background and it should do the task.
Hope it helps. happy coding :)

Comment: Nope, I am not trying to set the striped background. I am trying to make the white rounded frame appear like in picture 2. :)

Comment: thats possible using UITableViewStyleGrouped, i thought u have that already set. and in the above code im just telling that u might have used the above 2 codes to set the cell background as an image, which should not be set. if u have some line in cellForRowAtIndexPath which sets cell background image, then remove it and it should do the task.

Comment: Yeap, I did set the tableview style to grouped and I did not set any line in the cellForRowAtIndexPath which sets the cell background image. I do not know what went wrong! :( Thanks for the help anyway!

Answer (score 2):

In the first image, your `UITableView` style is `UITableViewStylePlain`, you should initialize it with `UITableViewStyleGrouped` to look like the table view in the second image

If you have a `xib`, you should set that property in the `xib`. If you are creating it by code, just change it in the initialization line.

Comment: The funny thing is that I did set my property to group in xib.